# Python Request Module Taking too Long , how to rerun if takes longer than x seconds?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using a proxy with python request.

However, it is not too reliable. Sometimes the random proxy used takes only a second, sometimes it takes more than a minute and forever.

How do I manually set if has been more than x seconds and the request has not receive response, we make a new request using another proxy form list?

```
  proxies = {'https': "proxyhere"}

    response = requests.get(url,proxies=proxies)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
try:
    response = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies, timeout=5)
except:
    response = requests.get(url, proxies=another_proxies)
```